# Removing one character hash / pound symbol from the start

Tags: javascript, regex

I stumbled across [this article](http://www.queness.com/post/328/a-simple-ajax-driven-website-with-jqueryphp) which was talking about AJAX and jQuery and I reached this line

```
hash = hash.replace(/^.*#/, '');
```

where hash is in the form #page1,#page2 etc...

Now what I don't understand is why

```
hash = hash.replace(/^#/, '');
```

will not suffice. From the [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions),

`^`   Matches beginning of input. If the multiline flag is set to true, also matches immediately after a line break character.

So with this caret alone I should be able to match the hash value, what is the author trying to do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your proposed regex will match only a hash symbol right at the beginning of the string, and nowhere else. The first regex you posted will match everything up to the the first hash symbol in the string.

Comment: Oh okay, I understand now for a click on the link my regex would work since it is just the href but would fail for the full link `example.com/#page1`

Answer (score 1):

`.*` means "any number of any characters", so it looks as though the author thinks that something might precede the octothorpe. You're correct in assuming that your simpler pattern will work, too.

Comment: Yeah I see that now so I was correct for the href one `#page1` just not a full link. Thanks I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

The first form will remove the hash, and *anything leading up to it*. So if it's really the location hash, it should not matter. If you had a full URL, you would be left with just the post-# part.

Comment: Yeah exactly if it is just the hash value #page1 it should not matter